# Rails serializable_hash error for nil columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

Having a bug where I cannot render json (I am getting thrown around a TypeError: nil is not a symbol) if one of my columns is nil.

Something like User.first.serializable_hash throws an error like this:

```
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `block in serializable_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `serializable_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:17:in `serializable_hash'
```

Anyone ever run into this problem? I know I can use activemodel serializers but I would have to put one on for every single model (and i can't turn it off for a specific controller).

Also: I am using rails 4 to build an api and using mysql2 adapter gem if that matters

Comment: maybe it will be useful for you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13635

Comment: thanks this does seem to be the issue. i am using composite primary keys gem to resolve it